# Oracle select most recent values by date

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have a number of database records for experiments taken a number of weeks apart from each other, usually approximately 2-3 weeks apart. The goal is to select the most recent results by date to generate a report. Here is an example dataset. For this dataset the goal is to pick the last row since it is the most recent measurement taken for the `QL_ID` `P14404`.

`QL_ID`  is the primary key and `QL_VAL` are the measurements for the sample and `MEASUREMENT_DATE` is the date the measurements were taken. The table name is `QL_RESULTS`.  I am able to get the most recent date and the `QL_ID` by using the query below, but I'm stuck on how to get all 3 columns i.e. `QL_VAL,QL_ID,MEASUREMENT_DATE`.

```
SELECT QL_ID,MAX(MEASUREMENT_DATE) FROM QL_RESULTS
GROUP BY QL_ID
```

---

```
  QL_VAL  QL_ID       MEASUREMENT_DATE 
  25      P14404        01-JUL-10
  30      P14404        15-JUL-10
  21      P14404        29-JUN-10
```

Comment: I saw numerous solutions but known was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `rank` your rows per `ql_id` according to the measurement date:

```
SELECT ql_val, ql_id, measurement_date
FROM   (SELECT ql_val, ql_id, measurement_date,
               RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ql_id
                            ORDER BY measurement_date DESC) AS rk 
        FROM   ql_results) t
WHERE  rk = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the slim solution is this one:

```
SELECT QL_ID, MAX(MEASUREMENT_DATE), 
   MAX(QL_VAL) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY MEASUREMENT_DATE) as QL_VAL
FROM QL_RESULTS
GROUP BY QL_ID;
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Also works, It'd be nice if I could accept both solutions.

Comment: @BreenDeen, you can at least make an upvote :-)